# Способы мультиязычности программ на Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x, локализация

При разработке приложения с поддержкой нескольких языковых локализаций, я использую файл, в котором храню все строковые данные программы. Раньше я обходился простым -

```
exec(open("файл/языковой/локолизации").read())
```

инициализируя таким образом все переменные со строковыми значениями в основной код приложения.

Сейчас exec как-то не хочется использовать. Я приспособил для этих целей модуль ConfigParser. Сейчас это выглядит вот так:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser


config = ConfigParser()
config.read("locale.ini")
language = config.get("LOCALE", "language")  # устанавливаем локаль
section = language.upper()
config.read("{}.ini".format(language))  # читаем файл строковых данных

# Таким образом я получаю строковые значения для приложеничя.
program_title = config.get(section, "program_title")
```

locale.ini
(файл текущей локализации приложения):

```
[LOCALE]
language = english
```

english.ini
(файл со строковыми данными):

```
[ENGLISH]
program_title = Clean Master
```

Теперь, скажем, если мне нужно сменить язык на русский, я добавляю файл russian.ini со строками русской локализации, а в файле locale.ini устанавливаю значение "language" в "russian".

Получается следующее:

locale.ini 
(файл текущей локализации приложения):

```
[LOCALE]
language = russian
```

english.ini 
(файл со строковыми данными):

```
[RUSSIAN]
program_title = Мастер Очистки
```

Может быть в Python есть другие варианты вышеописанного велосипеда?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, есть довольно стандартный вариант - использовать библиотеку [**gettext**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext), для которой есть биндинги в том числе и для Python (причем, в [стандартной библиотеке](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/gettext.html), не исключено, что это реализация **gettext** на Python).

Принцип работы примерно такой: все строки, подлежащие переводу оборачиваются в вызов специальной функции `_()`.

Далее, программа обрабатывается утилитой `pygettext`, вытаскивающей все переводимые строки, в результате получается файл `.pot` (шаблон перевода), в который в дальнейшем можно добавить перевод. Это текстовый файл с относительно простой внутренней структурой, его можно редактировать чем-то блокнотоподобным, но есть и специализированные утилиты, например, [poedit](https://poedit.net/), также его можно загрузить на какой-нибудь из сервисов онлайн-перевода типа [crowdin.com](http://crowdin.com) или [transifex.com](http://transifex.com), и редактировать там совместно с другими переводчиками.

Из файла `.pot` получается файл `.po` (по сути тот же `.pot`, но с заполненным переводом строк на нужный язык), который потом компилируется в файл `.mo` (бинарный файл, хотя тоже с довольно простой внутренней структурой) с помощью утилиты `msgfmt` из пакета `gettext` или утилиты `msgfmt.py` из пакета Python.

Далее, перевод импортируется в переводимую программу при помощи команды `gettext.install('mary', './locale', unicode=True)` (пример [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/73554/), реальные параметры могут быть другими).

Парочка нагугленных руководств:

- [Международные ягнята / Хабрахабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/73554/)
- [Локализация Python-скриптов при помощи gettext](https://dsent.me/blog/2014/10/12/python-scripts-gettext-l10n/)

Если потребуется редактировать перевод онлайн совместно с другими переводчиками, могу сказать, что упомянутые выше **crowdin** и **transifex** бесплатны для Opensource продуктов, но в **crowdin** с этим [довольно строго](https://crowdin.com/page/open-source-project-setup-request), в то время как в **transifex** достаточно того, чтобы перевод был доступен публично, и в настройках проекта была ссылка на исходный код. При этом субъективно у **crowdin** более дружелюбный интерфейс.

Comment: Видел я данные статьи. Просто мне показалось, что gettext - еще более велосипедистый велосипед, чем тот, который я использую :)

Comment: @Xyanight, ну, это довольно бородатый велосипед, вокруг которого уже сложилась своя инфраструктура. Наличие спец. редакторов и поддержка сервисами онлайн переводов уже о чем-то говорят. Плюс, он, например, поддерживает возможность указания различного перевода в зависимости от числительного (1 - "велосипед", 2 - "велосипеда", 5 - "велосипедов"), возможность автоматического слияния имеющегося перевода с обновленным шаблоном, и другие плюшки